# Flutter - How implement a file, image and camera picker for local storage

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

[image]

Hi, I would like to implement something like this in flutter. A button from which I can upload local photos from the camera or from images and files in the device to the app. Once I have taken the file I want it to appear near the button with the preview of the file as shown in the example and with the possibility of removing them. What's the best way to do this? Is there a package that does these things?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is! The package is [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker).
To install it, add it as a dependency to your `pubspec.yaml` or run `flutter pub add image_picker`.

```
dependencies:
  image_picker: ^0.8.5
```

Here's an example of how I've used it in my recent app:

```
final XFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source:
 ImageSource.gallery); //This opens the gallery and lets the user pick the image
if (pickedFile == null) return; //Checks if the user did actually pick something

final File image = (File(pickedFile.path)); //This is the image the user picked
```

Once you've got the image, you could use a container to show it.

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      image: Image.file(image),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know image picker but how can I also upload documents as pdf?  I must necessarily add another package for that or there is something that allows me to do both?

Comment: Maybe file_picker: https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker. I've never tried the package before, but it seems to have the functionality you need.